# Weblogic deployement IE8 emulation

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, internet-explorer-8, weblogic, emulation

is it possible to customize a Weblogic Domain in order to force every web application deployed on it to emulate IE8?

Thanks so much,

Daniele

Comment: Your question does not make sense. Web applications do not emulate Internet Explorer, web browsers do.

Comment: If you send to the client a page containing the tag <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9"> the browser will emulate IE 9. My question is: is it possible to programmatically insert that tag in every html message sent to the client?

Comment: I see. You can implement servlet filter in your particular web application. But I do not think that application server would do it for you for all applications. The other way would be some kind of apache proxy doing such translation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the purpose of my question was to identify IF it was possible to configure the application server in order to do that (and your answer is "no, it isn't"). Further question: are you 100% sure of that? :)

Comment: No. But there is nothing in J2EE known to me that would allow such functionality. Of course, there might be proprietary API of particular application server ..

Comment: Meta tags are usually only scraped when the document is loaded... so it would somehow have to be done beforehand. I don't think Weblogic can do this for you. Why not just do a massive `sed` command to change all of your pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to do that in the content server, but it is possible in the web server: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/cc817573.aspx)